# angular 2 auto refresh page after successful submission

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-services

I am building an angular website in which i am displaying couple of data when the page loads. I do some of the operation on these data like adding a new data using form submit or deleting the existing record etc.I want to update the view after these operations.Now i have two options

```
window.location.reload();
```

This causes the whole page to load creating simple unwanted delay and i have another option like

```
private refreshData(): void {
this.postsSubscription = this.postService.getPosts().subscribe(posts => {
    this.posts = posts;
    this.subscribeToData();
});
}

private subscribeToData(): void {
this.timerSubscription = Observable.timer(5000).first().subscribe(() => 
this.refreshData());
}
```

which hits the backend after certain time interval and re fetch the data.Now my question is ,which one is better ?Or is there any method which is more efficient than this.?Please help

Comment: Better to use Signalr or Firebase to support real-time functionality. By doing that, your server can send new data to client instead of the other way around with refresh interval.

Comment: use socket for real time data fetching which is more reliable

Comment: If i just have to use angular with simple java backend,whats the best way to go about this without using any sockets or signalr ...due to project constraints i am nt in liberty to use all these ..

Comment: is it possible to get the `adding a new data using form submit or deleting the existing record etc` directly on app load and then you can do all the operations in the view and once you are routing away if you are then save everything to the back end else opt for the 2nd option

Comment: @rahul ,i am little confused about "is it possible to get the adding a new data using form submit or deleting the existing record etc directly on app load and then you can do all the operations".can you elobarate

Comment: Its a quote fron your question where you told you are doing some operations on the form data , i just asked if it was possible to load all the backend data at start and do the manipulation in the view itself

Comment: wouldn't it be costly in terms of page load if i fetch everything on page load